# Loop select into select with cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, cursor

Data will be like this:

Schema of Table 1:

```
+-----+--+
|Name |Id|
+-----+--+
|Alias|1 |
+-----+--+
|adam |2 |
+-----+--+
```

Schema of Table 2:

```
+-----+--+
|order|id|
+-----+--+
|ord1 |1 |
+-----+--+
|ord2 |1 |
+-----+--+
|ord3 |1 |
+-----+--+
|ord4 |2 |
+-----+--+
|ord5 |2 |
+-----+--+
```

The result I want is this:

```
+-----+-+
|Alias|1|
+-----+-+
|ord1 |1|
+-----+-+
|ord2 |1|
+-----+-+
|ord3 |1|
+-----+-+
|adam |2|
+-----+-+
|ord4 |2|
+-----+-+
|ord5 |2|
+-----+-+
```

I tried this with cursor:

```
DECLARE @name, @id, @order
DECLARE curs_Fp CURSOR FOR

SELECT  c.name, c.id, o.order FROM customer c INNER JOIN ORDER o ON c.id = o.id

OPEN curs_Fp
FETCH NEXT FROM curs_Fp INTO  @name, @id, @order

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN

        SELECT @name, @id 

      --here I spose to do something for loopping every orders to a customer where  c.id = o.id
        SELECT @order, @id

FETCH NEXT FROM curs_Fp INTO @name, @id, @order
END

CLOSE curs_Fp
DEALLOCATE curs_Fp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This .............. it is working

```
create table #table (name varchar(30),[order] varchar(10),id varchar(3))

DECLARE @name varchar(30), @id int
DECLARE curs_Fp CURSOR FOR

SELECT  c.name, c.id FROM customer c 

OPEN curs_Fp
FETCH NEXT FROM curs_Fp INTO  @name, @id

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN

        insert into #table 
        SELECT @name, @id ,''

        insert into #table 
        SELECT  '',o.[order],o.id FROM ORDER o where  o.id = @id

FETCH NEXT FROM curs_Fp INTO  @name, @id
END

CLOSE curs_Fp
DEALLOCATE curs_Fp

select * from #table
drop table #table
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your a little confused about how cursors work.  Try this

```
DECLARE @name, @id, @order
DECLARE curs_Fp CURSOR FOR

SELECT  c.name, c.id, FROM customer c  -- first i select everthing in the customer table

OPEN curs_Fp
FETCH NEXT FROM curs_Fp INTO  @name, @id

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN

        print @name;
        SELECT order , id from order where id = @id  -- Now i get the orders for the customer
FETCH NEXT FROM curs_Fp INTO @name, @id
END

CLOSE curs_Fp
DEALLOCATE curs_Fp
```

You could probably do this with a simple select as well.  The results should be similar to what you wanted

```
 SELECT  c.name, o.id, o.order FROM customer c INNER JOIN ORDER o ON c.id = o.id
 order by name, o.order
```

Let me know if they dont work.  I didnt create your tables to test it.